# Как можно сократить код

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.navigate.viewpager1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Pavel on 21.02.2016.
 */
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
    ImageView[] arr_imageA = new ImageView[7];
    ImageView[] arr_imageB = new ImageView[7];
    ImageView[] arr_imageC = new ImageView[7];
    int pageNumber;



    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
/////////

        //////////////////

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        arr_imageA[0] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        arr_imageA[1] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        arr_imageA[2] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        arr_imageA[3] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        arr_imageA[4] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        arr_imageA[5] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        arr_imageA[6] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_imageA.length; i++) {
            arr_imageA[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    Intent myIntent = null;
                    switch (v.getId()) {

                        case R.id.imageView1:
                            arr_imageA[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                    arr_imageA[0].startAnimation(anim);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a1.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);

                                }
                            });

                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView2:
                            arr_imageA[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                    arr_imageA[1].startAnimation(anim);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a2.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView3:
                            arr_imageA[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                    arr_imageA[2].startAnimation(anim);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a3.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView4:
                            arr_imageA[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                    arr_imageA[3].startAnimation(anim);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a4.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView5:
                            arr_imageA[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                    arr_imageA[4].startAnimation(anim);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a5.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView6:
                            arr_imageA[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                    arr_imageA[5].startAnimation(anim);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a6.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView7:
                            arr_imageA[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                    arr_imageA[6].startAnimation(anim);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a7.class));
                                        }
                                    }, 100);
                                }
                            });
                    }

                    return false;
                }

            });
            if (pageNumber == 1) {
                View rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);


                arr_imageB[0] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b1);
                arr_imageB[1] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b2);
                arr_imageB[2] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b3);
                arr_imageB[3] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b4);
                arr_imageB[4] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b5);
                arr_imageB[5] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b6);
                arr_imageB[6] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.b7);
                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {
                    arr_imageB[j].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            Intent myIntent = null;
                            switch (v.getId()) {

                                case R.id.b1:
                                    arr_imageB[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageB[0].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),b1.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b2:
                                    arr_imageB[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageB[1].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),b2.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b3:
                                    arr_imageB[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageB[2].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),b3.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b4:
                                    arr_imageB[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageB[3].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),b4.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b5:
                                    arr_imageB[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageB[4].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),b5.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b6:
                                    arr_imageB[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageB[5].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),b6.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b7:
                                    arr_imageB[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageB[6].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),b7.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                            }

                      return false;  }

                    });
                }

                return rootViewB;
            }
            /////////////////////////
            if (pageNumber == 2) {
                View rootViewC = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);


                arr_imageC[0] = (ImageView) rootViewC.findViewById(R.id.c1);
                arr_imageC[1] = (ImageView) rootViewC.findViewById(R.id.c2);
                arr_imageC[2] = (ImageView) rootViewC.findViewById(R.id.c3);
                arr_imageC[3] = (ImageView) rootViewC.findViewById(R.id.c4);
                arr_imageC[4] = (ImageView) rootViewC.findViewById(R.id.c5);
                arr_imageC[5] = (ImageView) rootViewC.findViewById(R.id.c6);
                arr_imageC[6] = (ImageView) rootViewC.findViewById(R.id.c7);
                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageC.length; j++) {
                    arr_imageC[j].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            Intent myIntent = null;
                            switch (v.getId()) {

                                case R.id.c1:
                                    arr_imageC[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageC[0].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),c1.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.c2:
                                    arr_imageC[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageC[1].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),c2.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.c3:
                                    arr_imageC[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageC[2].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),c3.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.c4:
                                    arr_imageC[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageC[3].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),c4.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.c5:
                                    arr_imageC[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageC[4].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),c5.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.c6:
                                    arr_imageC[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageC[5].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),c6.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case R.id.c7:
                                    arr_imageC[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                            arr_imageC[6].startAnimation(anim);
                                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),c7.class));
                                                }
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    });
                            }

                     return false;   }

                    });
                }

                return rootViewC;
            }

        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы добавили в вопрос пояснения, зачем этот код нужен, что и как он делает.

Comment: суть такова:
3 экрана layout ан которых по 7 imageview с уникальным id , в данном коде я отлавливаю касания по каждому и воспроизвожу анимацию, хотел бы узнать,можно ли как-то код сократить или оставить как есть

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй  в методе

```
 arr_imageA[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ...
```

сократить код между switch и кейсами, написав один метод, в котором ты будешь вызывать содержимое каждого case, а сам метод вызывай в этих кейсах с передачей параметров. У тебя вроде только значение элемента массива и и значение интента везде меняется. Передавай в этот один метод эти 2 параметра

Например,

```
case R.id.imageView7:
                        arr_imageA[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                arr_imageA[6].startAnimation(anim);
                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),a7.class));
                                    }
                                }, 100);
                            }
                        });
```

измени на

```
case R.id.imageView7:
                        arr_imageA[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                metod1(6, a7.class)

                        });
```

а метод1 будет примерно такой

```
public void metod1(int i,Class prinyatiy_class){    
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
                                arr_imageA[i].startAnimation(anim);
                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),prinyatiy_class));
                                    }
                                }, 100);
                            }
                        });}
```

Я так, на скорую руку написал, но это должно работать и код твой сократит